# High concurrency system on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

Here is my situation.
I have a project hosted on Google Cloud, more specifically GAE (NodeJS) and Firestore.

I have a queue stored on Firestore that it could be up to 30 - 40k entries.

Each entry is basically an object with which I'll have to make an api call to an external service.

That external service allows only 10 requests/s for one IP.

At the moment I take batches of 10 and make for each one an api call, but it's to slow.

I already tried to instantiate multiple instances of the GAE service, but I still hit the limitation ( the instances use the same ip ?! ).

Another option would be to move the making of the api call in a Cloud Function and hit it there, but I think that I would bet the same outcome as with the GAE instances.

So, what do you think ?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, outgoing requests made by all GAE instances of the same app service will have the same source IP address. I tend to agree with your assumption that the same will be true for Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the requests per second per IP limit is put in place to throttle the overall amount of incoming requests and gaming this rule may cause issue to that service. The best way to handle this situation is either to get a paid subscription or to discuss the issue directly with the service provider.

Regarding the App Engine instances and IP addresses the short answer is:

No, GAE instances don't have their own dynamic IPs.

For more reference you can confirm it in the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) for App Engine:

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the same App Engine application. DNS might return different IP addresses to access App Engine over time or from different network locations.

tcptraceroute to a google service shows one of these points:

```
lga34s14-in-f14.1e100.net
```

According to the description of [Google Edge Network](https://peering.google.com/#/infrastructure):

> Our Edge Points of Presence (PoPs) are where we connect Google's network to the rest of the internet via peering. We are present on over 90 internet exchanges and at over 100 interconnection facilities around the world.

**To sum it up**: your application should exit the Google's network from the Edge Point closest to it's target it would make sense that it's always the same point with the same IP and from the amount of the services and the client applications GCP hosts you can expect a reverse proxy being used by Google.